# Is it possible to start a client-side app from Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, client, certificate, executable

I have a simple company portal which allows users to start their apps from the browser. The URLs in the hypelinks are passed (using Javascript) to a signed applet to actually start the client-side apps. All clients are XP or Vista and all run IE6 or IE7.

I have recently been looking at Silverlight and am wondering if I could do something similar. Ideally, I'd like to do everything from Silverlight and get rid of the applet.

Is it possible to call client-side apps from Silverlight? Can I sign a Silverlight app to give it extra rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call javascript from silverlight just as use use javascript with links.

For example to call `somefunction` with parameter:

```
HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("somefunction", new string[] { "parameter1" });
```

There's a good video about Html Browser integration [here](http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=65683)

Comment: yes, but what about starting an executable on the client? Is that possible?

Comment: No. Silverlight doesn't have access to local system and cannot do this by itself. It's sandboxed by design and you cannot do much to give it more permissions.

You either have to use some sort of applet to do this (activex) that can be communicated using javascript or deploy custom application on client machine that will communicate with silverlight using local ports.

Comment: shame. I was hoping to be able to consolidate HTML, Javascript, AJAX, Applets into one Silverlight app. Obviously not the silver bullet I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You should revisit this now that Silverlight 4 is out. You can see how to run an exe from [HERE.](http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/michaelwolf?entry=silverlight_4_and_command_line%20)